# fail to compile substrate add-a-pallet

Tags: substrate

I got the compile error when I follow the latest substrate tutorial add-a-pallet.
compiler complain about the bind error u128 type doesn't satisfied with Event.
Using rustc version: rustc 1.57.0-nightly (54bb4fec6 2021-10-08)

```
Compiling node-template-runtime v3.0.0-monthly-2021-10 (/home/bruce/substrate-node-template/runtime)
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v3.0.0-monthly-2021-10 (/home/bruce/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/bruce/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-41f26d4f5bdef0b7/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/home/bruce/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.57.0-nightly (54bb4fec6 2021-10-08)


  --- stderr
     Compiling node-template-runtime v3.0.0-monthly-2021-10 (/home/bruce/substrate-node-template/runtime)
  error[E0277]: the trait bound `u128: Currency<AccountId32>` is not satisfied in `Event`
     --> /home/bruce/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:303:1
      |
  303 | / construct_runtime!(
  304 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  305 | |         Block = Block,
  306 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  320 | |     }
  321 | | );
      | |__^ within `Event`, the trait `Currency<AccountId32>` is not implemented for `u128`
      |
  note: required because it appears within the type `Event`

  error: could not compile `node-template-runtime` due to 10 previous errors
```

Comment: Show the output from "rustup show", please.

Comment: ```Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/bruce/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
wasm32-wasi
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.55.0 (c8dfcfe04 2021-09-06)```

Answer (score 0):

`Substrate Node Template` does not compile on any version of Rust compiler compiler. I suggest to:

1. execute `init.sh` script in `scripts` directory
2. working versions on my end looks like below:

   stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
3. `rustup default stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

After applying those two suggestions you should be able to compile source code.

Comment: Thank you！But nothing changed after I apply your suggestions. working version on my end looks like:
```Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu    
rustup home:  /home/bruce/.rustup  

installed toolchains  
--------------------  

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)  
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu  
1.55.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu  

active toolchain    
----------------  

1.55.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (overridden by '/home/bruce/nearcore/rust-toolchain')  
rustc 1.55.0 (c8dfcfe04 2021-09-06)```
is it right?

Comment: Have you exectuted: "rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly"? Could you say what have you have done in order to run it? Look at: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-node-template/blob/master/docs/rust-setup.md

Comment: Join to the channel and ask the question, I will help you: https://riot.im/app/#/room/#substrate-technical:matrix.org

Comment: yes！the unknow target has been added before. And I run the init.sh then set the default working version, but nothing changed!

Comment: I have questioned in the room but get no response!囧

Comment: Maybe in the Twitter's thread you will find an answer: https://twitter.com/tomaszwaszczyk/status/1343512637909458944. If not write in the question explicitly what have you done in order to compile.